# How to avoid typing smiley in Cordova Android Application

Tags: android, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am working in Mobile Application using Cordova v5.3.3, Html5, Angaular JS, Bootstrap v3.1.1. In that application i have one popup textarea combination of angular js custom directive and bootstrap.
            For auto focusing the popup am using shown.bs.modal event. Once the textarea is focused the keyboard is opening automatically for typing it contains smiley/emotions. I want to avoid typing smiley/emotion on that textarea is there any ways to do it?
            I  tried the below approaches/solution but that is not working

```
        1. onkeypress and ng-keypress event is not working android Tab(Samsung Galaxy Tab SM-T231 Android OS 4.4.2)
        2. onkeyup and onkeydown with Regex replace not working because the event get fired once the character is typed 
        3. Tried some keyboard plugins but not helpful.
                3.1 https://github.com/phonostar/PhoneGap-SoftKeyboard
                3.2 https://github.com/macdonst/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard 
                3.3 https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard 
        4. Try to hide softkeyboard using below configuration in config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml file but not working.

                    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateHidden"/>
                    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />  ----in config.xml

                    In AndroidManifest.xml file
                    <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" ... > ... </activity>

        5.  In MainActivity.java class i was tried some approaches was listed blow 


                    The below code is written inside the onCreate method.
                5.1 
                     this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                     this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED);
                5.2     
                     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getContentView().getWindowToken(), 0);

                5.3  Created one Javascript interface and try to fire the event from javascript

                         class JSInterface {
                                @JavascriptInterface
                                public void hideKeyboard() {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                           try {
                                                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                                    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(MainActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
```

unfortunately this is also not helpful to me. Anyone faced this issue any alternative solution for this? anyone help me out for this issue?